# Traversal to combine multiple map operations into single ADT

Tags: haskell, traversal, haskell-lens, lenses

Given a record consisting of multiple maps, how can I write a traversal (or prism, or `Lens' TestLens (Maybe Interim)`) that allows me to group together lookups?

First off, my current attempts.

```
data TestLens = TL
    { _foo1 :: Map.Map Text Int
    , _foo2 :: Map.Map Text Bool
    , _foo3 :: Map.Map Text Text
    } deriving Show
 
tl = TL (Map.fromList [("a", 5), ("b", 6), ("c", 1), ("d", 3)])
         (Map.fromList [("b", True), ("c", False), ("d", True)])
         (Map.fromList [("c", "foo"), ("d", "bar")])
 
makeLenses ''TestLens
 
data Interim = Interim Int Bool Text deriving Show
data Interim2 = Interim2 Int Bool deriving Show

getOnePart s l k = s ^. l . at k
 
interim s k = Interim <$> getOnePart s foo1 k <*> getOnePart s foo2 k <*> getOnePart s foo3 k
interim2 s k = Interim2 <$> getOnePart s foo1 k <*> getOnePart s foo2 k
doTestStuff = tl ^.. folding (\s -> mapMaybe (interim s) (Map.keys $ s ^. foo1))
```

The intended behaviour is that `interim` (as it stands, it's a mishmash of lens and..not lens) combines `at` over multiple `Map`s:

```
interim tl "a" = Nothing
interim tl "c" = Just (Interim 1 False "foo")
```

and then I can fold over all possible keys to get the complete list of `Interim`s.

What I'd like to be able to do is build an indexed traversal (rather than an unindexed fold) over all possible `Interim`s, but so far I've had no luck in the combo of `itraversed` I need here..I suspect because I flip between `map` and `lens`:

```
itraverseInterim2s = ...

> tl ^@.. itraverseInterim2s
[("b", Interim2 6 True), ("c", Interim2 1 False), ("d", Interim2 3 True)]
-- and if we assume there exists _1 :: Lens' Interim2 Int
> tl & itraverseInterim2s . _1 %~ (+5)
TL (Map.fromList [("a", 5), ("b", 11), ("c", 6), ("d", 8)])
         (Map.fromList [("b", True), ("c", False), ("d", True)])
         (Map.fromList [("c", "foo"), ("d", "bar")])
```

I can't equally work out if last behaviour is better solved by making a `Lens' TestLens (Maybe Interim2)`, a `k -> Prism' TestLens Interim2` (I think only one of these satisfies lens laws), or by having individual elements traversed with `itraverseInterim2s . index k`.

Obviously for every `InterimX` ADT I want to be able to extract from the combination of `fooX` maps I'll have to write minor boilerplate but that bit's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered writing something like:

```hs
fanoutTraversal :: Traversal' s a -> Traversal' s b -> Traversal' s (a,b)
fanoutTraversal t1 t2 fab s =
  maybe (pure s) (fmap update . fab) mv
  where
    mv = liftA2 (,) (s ^? t1) (s ^? t2)
    update (c,d) = s & t1 .~ c & t2 .~ d
```

With this function, you can write `interim` as:

```hs
interim :: Text -> Traversal' TestLens Interim
interim k = (((foo1 . ix k) `fanoutTraversal` (foo2 . ix k)) `fanoutTraversal` (foo3 . ix k)) . interimIso
  where
    interimIso = iso (\((a,b),c) -> Interim a b c) (\(Interim a b c) -> ((a,b),c))
```

Things would need to change a little if you want to use `at` instead of `ix` or to use `IndexedTraversal` instead of `Traversal`, but the idea is hopefully sound.

---

If your goal is to traverse through all the `Interim`s in the `TestLens`, it may be easier to first convert `TestLens` to `Map.Map Text Interim` and then traverse that map:

```hs
import Control.Lens hiding ((<.>))
import Data.Functor.Apply (Apply(..)) -- could just as well use Map.intersectionWith

manyInterim :: Traversal' TestLens Interim
manyInterim = manyInterim' . traverse

-- Let's use this version of Interim so that we have record access
data Interim = Interim
  { i1 :: Int
  , i2 :: Bool
  , i3 :: Text
  } deriving Show

manyInterim' :: Lens' TestLens (Map.Map Text Interim)
manyInterim' = lens sa sbt
  where
    sa TL{..} = Interim <$> _foo1 <.> _foo2 <.> _foo3
    sbt TL{..} interimMap = TL
      { _foo1 = Map.union (i1 <$> interimMap) _foo1
      , _foo2 = Map.union (i2 <$> interimMap) _foo2
      , _foo3 = Map.union (i3 <$> interimMap) _foo3
      }
```

Comment: ooh, this seems excellent - thank you! I think `ix` over `at` is fine for my use case (I don't need to set to add missing elements) - though I'm now struggling to work out how to expand this to an `allInterim` traversal...some way of mapping over `Map.keys (_foo1 tl)` inside the traversal?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to map over all the keys using the first method either, but I updated the answer to include a second method that's more reasonable for dealing with all `Interim`s in one traversal.